# Removing all .DS_store files via sudo command in Synology SSH

Tags: ssh, nas, synology

When running the following command:

```
find / -name .DS_Store -delete
```

it will find all the files but fails to delete as it doesn't have the correct permissions to do so. however when running:

```
Sudo find / -name .DS_Store -delete
```

it just hangs and nothing happens. I know that on Synology DSM6 root access for SSH has been disabled, and I'm logged in as an Admin, theoretically running the Sudo command should work?

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` would be more portable, as `Sudo` will not exist on most other OS.

`find -x / ...` will help keep `find` out of problematic mount points such as `/dev` or other remote filesystems, though you may need to check `df` to see if there are `/Volumes/foodrive` that `find` does need to go through.

Otherwise try `find / -print` to see where the command gets hung up.